# Make horizontal RecyclerView pagination inside vertical RecyclerView just like Google's Play Store Apps home page

Tags: java, android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make item pagination for each horizontal RecyclerView populated by vertical RecyclerView. So that lazy loading of each horizontal items list can be done. I have tried using 'addOnScrollListener' a recycler view listener for the scroll detection. But couldn't achieve the pagination on the horizontal list just like below screenshot. Here, I have attached a screenshot of google play store horizontal recycler view pagination.

Here, the screenshot shows the pagination on each of the horizontal list which was populated by the vertical RecyclerView. Please help me out, how can I achieve this type of pagination?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `couldn't achieve the desired output.`

Comment: "Desired output" means pagination just like above screenshots. I have also edited the question.

Comment: maybe [Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) library can help?

Comment: @KabindraShrestha could you achieve this functionality. Even I require the same but stuck at pagination. It would be helpful if you could let me know how you did this.

Comment: @PrahladVThej I have achieved this functionality using nested recycler view and notified data to the same list object through 'addOnScrollListener' to paginate the list.